# How can i sort for every word in a string for every string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, sorting

For starters i did this

`text = "Hello I want to make this code better"`

`x = text.split()`

`sorted_characters = sorted(x[5])`

`sortedword = "".join(sorted_characters)`

`print(sortedword)`

I want the code to do this but i couldn't figure out how to seperate words and every string in list:

`example=['I like python', 'I like reading books']`

Output should be `['I eikl hnopty', 'I eikl adeginp bkoos']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one liner:
`[' '.join([''.join(sorted(z)) for z in i.split()]) for i in example]`

This just does what you did, with the list comprehension feature of python, and sort every element in the list

Comment: how can i make it output 'ouy acn go aefrst ahnt 015', 'adiikklt ckllouuy' without it being a list and comma not being a string ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but if you mean how to convert it to a string you could just ', '.join() the comprehended list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to get the words out of the sentence and sort each of them and add them to a new string, like this...

```py
text = "Hello I want to make this code better"
res = ""

for i in text.split():
    temp = ""

    for j in sorted(i):
        temp += j

    res += f"{temp} "

print(res)
```

Comment: for j in sorted(i):
        temp += j

    res += f"{temp} " what did you do here can you explain i haven't learnt these things :D and are there any alternatives i can do ?

Comment: @PitonGamer - For example, `i += 1` is the same as `i = i + 1`. (It’s a carry-over from C). In Python the same logic can apply to strings.  It’s adding a new string to the existing string.